# Binding an event during an update() transition

Tags: d3.js

Is it possible to bind an event to a selection during a transition?

For example, let's say this is your update:

```
        g3.selectAll(".circles")
          .data(dataFiltered, function(d){ return d['token']})
          .transition().delay(circleDelay).duration(1200)
              .attr('r', pointRadius + "px")
              .attr('stroke', '#fff')
              .attr('stroke-width', 1.5)
              .attr("fill",function(d,i){ return (typeof(d[3]) === 'string') ? colorize(d[3]) : null })
              .style('cursor',"pointer")
              .attr('class',"circles");
```

It throws an error to chain `.on('mouseover',function mouseoverlogic(){});`

During the `enter().update().exit()` pattern, can events be bound to existing selections before the `exit()`?

Comment: If you put the `.on(...)` after `.transition()`, you'd be binding the handler to the transition and not the selection. But yes, in general you can certainly bind event handlers to selections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since transitions are a special kind of selections you cannot use all methods available to a selection on a transition. Instead, use [transition.each()](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#each) to bind your handler to the elements in the transition.

```
.transition()
    .each(function () {
        d3.select(this).on('mouseover', function mouseoverlogic() {});
    });
```