# Getting error on applying transition in d3

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js

I am trying to apply some transition effect on bar graph i designed in d3. Here is my code-

```
svg.selectAll(".bar")
            .data(data)
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "bar")
            .append("rect")
            .attr("rx", barRadius)
            .attr("fill","333" )
            // .attr("color_value", "steelblue")
            .attr("index_value", function(d, i) {
                return "index-" + d[columns[0]].replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '', 'gi');
            })
            .attr("class", function(d, i) {
                return "bars-Bubble-index-" + d[columns[0]].replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '', 'gi')+div;
            })
            .attr("id", function(d) {
                return d[columns[0]] + ":" + d[measure1];
            })
            .attr("onclick", fun)
            .attr("x", function(d) {
                return x(d[columns[0]]);
            })
            .attr("width",0)
            .transition()
            .duration(2000)//1 second
            .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
            .attr("y", function(d) {
                return y(d[measure1]);
            })
            .attr("height", function(d) {
                return height - y(d[measure1]);
            })
```

Transition seem to be working fine except for the fact that I am receiving following errors on browser console
TypeError: svg.selectAll(...).data(...).enter(...).append(...).attr(...).append(...).attr(...).attr(...).attr(...).attr(...).attr(...).attr(...).attr(...).attr(...).transition(...).duration(...).attr(...).attr(...).attr(...).on is not a function 
TypeError: bars.append(...).attr(...).attr(...).transition(...).duration(...).attr(...).attr(...).transition(...).duration(...).attr(...).attr(...).attr(...).attr(...).attr(...).attr(...).attr(...).attr(...).on is not a function

And because of these error rest of the script is not working properly and graphs are displayed properly.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `.data(data)` is not chainable, try removing that if error persist, or add it at the end of chain

Comment: Thanks for help @Tushar but it didn't work

Comment: The error is the same, you are using method that is not chainable.

Comment: `fun` is being executed prematurely. Use `.on("click", fun)` instead of `.attr("onclick"...`

Comment: @Tushar your comments are incorrect. `.data()` returns the update selection. Of course it is chainable.

Comment: @Tushar Your assumption is not correct: selection.data(data) is perfectly chainable. You will see it that way in almost every example dealing with d3's data binding. You may want to check the [spec](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#data) for details.

Comment: Can you post your data ? or create a jsFiddle?

Comment: @ValarMorghulis Have you posted the entire statement? Looking at the error message I'd expect to see another call to `selection.on()` after the last `.attr()`. This would explain the error since the transition doesn't allow for binding listeners using `.on()`. I posted an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29118789/4235784) to another question which might help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the `.on(...)` call before the `.transition()`, then it should be fine.

Comment: I'm taking a look at this question because I am having a similar issue. I was wondering what had to go inside the on method in this situation?

Answer (score 2):

Calling `.transition()` will return the transition and not the results of your `selectAll("bar")`. So by calling `.on()` after calling `.transition()` you are attempting to attach your event listener to the transition instead of attaching to the elements in the `selectAll("bar")` selection. Move the call to `.on()` above the `.transition()` call and you'll get rid of the error.

Much example code uses `.style()` and `.attr()` on the `transition` object, to those learning D3 it appears as though they are operating on the selection. This is not the case as those operators actually set the end state of a `transition`. While this essentially has the same result as operating on the selection, it can cause confusion for newer folks like us.