# Word cloud unable to use onClick

Tags: javascript, d3.js, word-cloud

I'm building a wordcloud using Jason Davies d3.layout.cloud() https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud.git
I decided to add a transition and duration attributes to make the wordcloud look better when it arrives on the screen . However, I can't use on("click") attribute anymore since it sends me an error :
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
It refers to the line .on("click", function (d) {alert('ok');})
When I remove the transition and duration, the on click works correctly .
Here is the js code :

```
var fill = d3.scale.category20();


var layout = d3.layout.cloud().size([1500, 800])
        .words(frequency_list)
        .padding(5)
        .rotate(function() {return ~~(Math.random() -0.5) * 120;})
        .font("Impact")
        .fontSize(function(d) { return d.size; })
        .on("end", draw);

layout.start();


function draw(words) {
d3.select("svg").remove();
d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", layout.size()[0])
  .attr("height", layout.size()[1])
.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + layout.size()[0] / 2 + "," + layout.size()[1] / 2 + ")")
.selectAll("text")
  .data(words)
.enter().append("text")
.transition()
    .duration(function(d) { return d.time}  )
.attr('opacity', 1)
  .style("font-size", function(d) { return d.size + "px"; })
  .style("font-family", "Impact")
  .style("fill", function(d, i) { return fill(i); })
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
  })

  .style("cursor", "pointer")
  .text(function(d) { return d.text; })
  .on("click", function (d) {alert('ok');});
```

frequency_list is a list whose elements contain the attributes "text", "size", and "time" .
I don't know how to solve this .
Any help would be appraciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29118789/4235784) to a similar question: Since transitions are a special kind of selections, you cannot use all methods available to a selection on a transition. In your case this means, you are not allowed to use `on()` to register event handlers on a transition. Instead, use [transition.each()](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#each) to bind your handler to the elements in the transition.

```
.transition()
    // rest of your code
    .each(function () {
        d3.select(this).on("click", function (d) {alert('ok');});
    });
```

Comment: Or you can simply attach the click handler before the transition.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Yes, you are right. That briefly came to my mind and I'm not sure why I dropped the idea.